# How to connect booking table to car table using foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

I am trying to create a booking functionality where users can book a car for a specific amount of time:

I have set up all my User functionality using devise and this is what my user model looks like at the moment:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable,
      :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
      :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook , :google_oauth2]
end
```

I have also created a cars scaffold using rails g scaffold which hold the fields: `name`, `make`, `model`, `number_plate` and `color`

This is what my car model looks like at the moment:

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
end
```

I want to make a bookings scaffold that is connected to both the tables. So that when a user makes a booking they can input the car name into the booking form and it will associate the booking with the car that has the same name.

I was thinking of running the scaffold command like this:

```
rails g scaffold Booking user:references car:references start_time:string end_time:string car_name:string
```

where the car name is what is used to connect the booking to a specific car

and then specifying the relationships in the models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bookings
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable,
      :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
      :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook , :google_oauth2]   
end 

class Bookings < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :car , :foreign_key => "car_name",
end

class Car < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to and has_many :bookings
end
```

I havent tried making a booking scaffold yet and really just wanted to ask if im going in the right direction in terms of what i want to do before i start. Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't think you need this `Bookings has_one Car` unless you have a specific use case. `Car has_many Bookings and Booking belongs_to a Car` should be fine.
And in every booking, you can maintain a interval for duration, after which if the booking is not confirmed, you can delete that booking for the car.

Comment: Consider https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association, adding more cols to the join table (which can be Booking).

Comment: First, I wonder the validity of belongs_to and has_many :bookings, there is only has_and_belongs_to_many.. In the Booking model, you declared car:references where it means booking belongs to Car. The reference key type by default is bigint, you might need to declare it to string type so that it can match your car_name type?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is just a standard join model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :cars, through: :bookings
end 

class Bookings < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  # KISS. Just use an id for the foreign key
  belongs_to :car 
end

class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :users, through: :bookings
end
```

> I want to make a bookings scaffold that is connected to both the
>   tables. So that when a user makes a booking they can input the car
>   name into the booking form and it will associate the booking with the
>   car that has the same name.

This is bound to not be very user friendly in reality as the user would have to enter the name exactly like the value in the DB. You also want to stick to convention and use IDs for foreign key associations, [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Instead create a select:

```
<%= form_for(@booking) do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <%= f.label :car_id, 'Select your car' %>
    <%= f.collection_select :car_id, Car.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If you really want to have that exact feature you should implement it as an AJAX [autocomplete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete)*.

Comment: * don't ask: how do I do that? Its a really long subject and there are plenty of tutorials that cover it.